# Update a record in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an existing record from database that I have retrieved using Entity Framework:

```
 MyDataObject myExistingObject= _dbContext.data
   .Where(s => s.Id == myId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Externally, I have received another `MyDataObject newDataObjectForSameRow` that contains updated information for `myExistingObject` - all fields *except Primary Key*, that is initially set to 0 in the newDataObjectForSameRow.

How can I instruct Entity Framework "replace the row that has currently myExistingObject by newDataObjectForSameRow, however keeping the same Primary Key"?

Comment: Make changes to myExistingObject .. then, `_dbContext.Save()`

Comment: @Jawad but can I somehow re-attach Entity Framework to completely new object?

Comment: You should not keep two instanced of the same entity tracked at the same time. Either one of the object is your DTO then you need to map the properties from A to B (you could use automapper for this) or you should not have instantiated the second object in the first place. If you provide us with some code we can help better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
newDataObjectForSameRow.Id = myId;
MyDataObject myExistingObject = _dbContext.data.Where(s => s.Id == myId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
_dbContext.Entry(myExistingObject).CurrentValues.SetValues(newDataObjectForSameRow);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```